# jquery show div when :last is shown

Tags: jquery

As the title says I'm trying to get a div to show when `:last` is shown, here is what I have so far

```
$(function() {
    $('#d').hide();
    var $images = $('#d1 > .c1 > a').clone(),
        $imgShow = 0;
    $('#d1 > .c1').html($('#d1 > .c1 > a:first'));
    $('#d1 > .c1 > a').click(function(e) {
        var $n = $('img', $images).eq(++$imgShow).attr('src');
        $(this).children().attr('src', $n);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

​

[see jfiddle for demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EjGnK/3/)

I tried with on `:last` click but that didn't seem to work (hence it being commented out in jfiddle) plus having it be shown when `:last` is in view is a better option anyway, how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2):

`last` isn't working because you are manipulating the `DOM` with the `html()` call. A better approach would be to store the total image count, and then show the `div` when you have reached the last image (i.e., `totalImages == imgShow`):

```
var $images  = $('#d1 > .c1 > a').clone(),
    $imgShow = 0,
    totalImages = $images.length;

// ...

$('#d1 > .c1 > a').click(function(e) {
  var $n = $('img', $images).eq(++$imgShow).attr('src');
  $(this).children().attr('src', $n);
  e.preventDefault();

  if ($imgShow == totalImages) {
    $("#d").show();   
  }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EjGnK/4/).